# save option in input select after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've made a function with javascript that can add an option in input select if it not exist by selecting option other but after refresh the option added disappear I want to keep it after refresh but i don't know how to do it please if anyone can help i'll be very grateful

Comment: Please can you provide some code that shows what you have so far?  This way the quality of help on offer is likely to be better :)

Comment: Thank you for clarification i put the code below with answers

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible without having any backend that can save your option somewhere and populate your select option list latter from that saved options.

For this you have to populate your select box option from a array or something similar. Then when you add option to your select box using jquery you must update array. After refresh you will get new option appear properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use localStorage. When you populate an input, save it. And when you are going to draw the input, check if localStorage have the data, and prepopulate it

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cookie to save the value then re-populate on refresh

Angular

```
angular.module('ddlChoiceExample', ['ngCookies'])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$cookies', function($cookies) {
  // Retrieving a cookie
  var ddlChoice= $cookies.get('ddlChoice');
  // Setting a cookie
  $cookies.put('ddlChoice', 'Option1');
}]);
```

Or in JS

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my function to add option select:

```
     <script type="text/JavaScript"> function AjoutOptionAuSelect(this_select) {
if (this_select.value == "autreVille")
{
   var saisie;
  var pass = false;
  do
  {
    if (pass) alert("La valeur est incorrecte. Elle ne doit comporter que des lettres.");

    saisie = prompt("Entrer la nouvelle valeur :");

    if (saisie == null) return false;
    pass = true;
  }
  while (saisie.match(/[^a-z^éèàç]/i) && saisie != "")

  this_select.options[this_select.length] = new Option(saisie, saisie, true, true);

  for (var i=0; i < this_select.options.length; i++)
  {
    if (this_select.options[i].value == saisie)
    {
      this_select.options[i].selected = true;

    }
  }
} }</script>
```

and input select:

```
       <?= $this->Form->input('ville',
       array(
        'label'=> false,
      'options'   => array('Casablanca'=>'Casablanca','Rabat'=>'Rabat', 'Fès'=>'Fès','Tanger'=>'Tanger','Marrakech'=>'Marrakech',
       'Essaouira'=>'Essaouira','autreVille'=> 'autreVille' ), 
      'class'   => 'form-control ',
      'id'=>'ville',
      'onChange'=> "AjoutOptionAuSelect(this);"
     )
      ); ?>
```